# jQuery Animating divs to show full image, overlapping content and not moving content down

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, sliding

basically what I have is 4 divs, that each start at a set height and when you mouseover them, they animate to make the div taller, thus showing the background image in full rather than just a sneak peak of the image as shown originally. You can take a look at what i've got here:

http://jsfiddle.net/u2DK7/

Basically what I want it to do is when you hover over one of the boxes, it expands over the content rather than pushing it down. I've tried absolute positioning briefly, but it doesn't seem what I need.

The other thing I was wondering is whether there is any way to just make the animate instruction work once. Whilst hovering back over and forth and then watching the accordion style effect of animations you've queued up is pretty cool, it's not really how I want it to work!

By the way, I need the style tags kept in the html code so I can change the background image without setting up 4 individual divs!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose to absolutely position the elements, and calculate the distance they need to be from the left based on their previous sibling.

[working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/u2DK7/1/)

**The jQuery**

```
$.each($('.fourboxes'), function(i,v){
  if(i == 0){
   $(v).css('left', '10px');
  }else{
    var prevDiv = $(this).prev('.fourboxes');
    var pWidth = prevDiv.width();
    var pleft = prevDiv.position().left;
    $(v).css({'left' : pWidth + pleft + 10 +"px"});
  }        
});
```

**The CSS**

```
.fourboxes {
    position:absolute;
        left:10px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 139px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:blue !important;
```

}

Comment: That's great, but is there any way to align that to the parent div?

Comment: `position:absolute` elements are bound by the first parent container with a `position:relative`. using `top:0` and `left:0` will place you at the top left of the first `position:relative` container. From here, you can use calculations to make it appear fluid. I'm not sure I understand your question completely.

Comment: Ah, OH GOD WHY did I miss that! ;) Thank you!

Do you have any idea about how to stop the animations from repeating?